# Как реализовать запуск функции js при бездействии пользователя

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.
Помогите, пожалуйста.
Мне нужно, чтобы мой код js запускался при бездействии пользователя, но когда пользователь активизировался, нужно выключить мой код.

**Вот такой код:**

```
var $classLoop = $('.tab'),
    i = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    $classLoop.removeClass('active').filter($classLoop[i]).toggleClass('active');
    i < $classLoop.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0;
  }, 2000);
```

Вот, что я попробовал сделать, но после того, как пользователь начал двигать мышью и кликать ею, мой код (выше) остается активным. Мне его нужно выключить.

```
var no_active_delay = 3; // Количество секунд простоя мыши, при котором пользователь считается неактивным
  var now_no_active = 0; // Текущее количество секунд простоя мыши
  setInterval("now_no_active++;", 1000); // Каждую секунду увеличиваем количество секунд простоя мыши
  setInterval("updateChat()", 2000); // Запускаем функцию updateChat() через определённый интервал
  document.onmousemove = activeUser; // Ставим обработчик на движение курсора мыши
  function activeUser() {
    now_no_active = 0; // Обнуляем счётчик простоя секунд
  }
  function updateChat() {
    if (now_no_active >= no_active_delay) { // Проверяем не превышен ли "предел активности" пользователя
     
    var $classLoop = $('.tab'),
      i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
      $classLoop.removeClass('active').filter($classLoop[i]).toggleClass('active');
      i < $classLoop.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0;
    }, 2000);

      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer;
function activeUser() {
  cleartInterval(timer);
  ...

timer = setInterval(...
```

Comment: Можно подробнее? Не совсем понял.

Comment: @Максим Подробнее. 1. Добавьте переменную `timer`. 2. Добавьте строчку в функцию `activeUser`. 3. Добавьте `timer =` перед `setInterval`.

Comment: timer перед `setInterval("now_no_active++;", 1000);` и `setInterval("updateChat()", 2000);` вписать?

Comment: Не работает все равно, `timer =` ко всем `setInterval` перепробовал.